# Replace ALL text within a group of files

Tags: r, quotation-marks

I have a large group of files. I want to delete all the text within these files and paste a new string which I call `mytext`.

I'm new to R, but I've written an R code that nearly does the job perfectly. It's very messy and I'm sure I'm taking unnecessary steps. Furthermore, it doesn't quite delete all the text like I want, and it leaves quotation marks, which I can't have.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.Hdr")

for(x in 1:length(temp)) {
    data = read.csv(temp[x], header = FALSE)
    data <- data[NULL, NULL]
    write.csv(data, file = temp[x])    ## output new file
}
temp = list.files(pattern = "*.Hdr")
mytext = "nrows 4096
ncols 8192
nbands 1
nbits 16
pixeltype signedint
byteorder M
layout dat
ulxmap -130.517083333328
ulymap 58.2329166666644
xdim 0.00833333333
ydim 0.00833333333"    ## This is the variable I want to keep

for(x in 1:length(temp)) {
    data = read.csv(temp[x], header = FALSE)
    data = paste(mytext)
    write.csv(data, file = temp[x])    ## output new file
}
```

My resulting tables all look like this:

```
"","x"
"1","nrows 4096
ncols 8192
nbands 1
nbits 16
pixeltype signedint
byteorder M
layout dat
ulxmap -130.517083333328
ulymap 58.2329166666644
xdim 0.00833333333
ydim 0.00833333333"
```

Which is nearly perfect, but I don't want:

```
"","x",
"1",
```

Nor do I want the quotation marks around `mytext`. I'd appreciate someone with more experience pointing out my mistake.

Comment: `write.csv(data, file = temp[x], header=F, row.names=F, quote=F)`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick! Would you like to post your comment as an answer and get a green checkmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at are the column headers and row names. You can turn those off along with the quoting with

```
write.csv(data, file = temp[x], header=F, row.names=F, quote=F)
```